# A bound for $x$ in an inequality.

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Is there an expression or bound for $x,\varepsilon>0$ that satisfies $$x^{4(2x-1)}<n^{(x-1)(2x-3)\varepsilon}?$$

Comment: Is $n$ given? Are you looking for a bound such that the inequality holds for **all** n? $n\in \mathbf N$?

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit of course at all large enough $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking, as $x^{4x(2x-1)}\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: @user254665 The OP is asking to set an upper bound on $x$ such that the inequality holds.

Comment: Taking logs, the expression is equivalent to $$\frac{4(2x-1)\log x}{(x-1)(2x-3)\epsilon} < \epsilon \log n.$$ Using very rough estimates: This fails if $x$ is sufficiently close to $0$, for example if $x < 1/4$ and $x < n^{-\epsilon}$. It also fails if $x$ is sufficiently close to $3/2$ with $x > 3/2$, for example if $$\frac{3}{2} < x < \frac{3}{2} + \frac{16 \log(3/2)}{2 \epsilon  \log n}.$$ It holds for all $x$ large enough, for example it holds for all $x > 3$ when $1/e < \epsilon \log n$. I suppose the kind of answer you want depends on how sharp you need these estimates to be.